# Can't install CloudBees SDK onto Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, cloudbees, java-home

I seem to have some problems initialising the CloudBees SDK locally to be able to run a simple application.

I've downloaded the SDK, added the required paths; everything ok up to the point where I am trying to execute the bees run command from my newly created application folder.
The error I get seems related to the JDK installation on my computer - JAVA_HOME is pointing to C:\Program Files\Java\jre7 and not to jdk .

I've checked all the local PATHS and they seem ok.

By the way I am using Windows 8.0 Enterprise 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Fully uninstalling Java from my system followed by installing only the 64bit version and recreating System paths seems to have fixed the problem.